# Counting with multiple conditions across columns

Tags: excel, date, conditional-statements

I am trying to work out how to count over two columns with conditions including a date range rather than text or value.

Column A dates (written in dd,mm,yyyy format), 
Column B text (apples, pears, bananas etc.)

I would like to count, how many apples were bought between 1st & 31st Jan. 
I first needed to work out how many entries there were for each month:

**=Sumproduct((A1:A100>=date(2003,1,1))*(A1:A100<=date(2003,1,31)** and so on. But I think there must be an easier formula for that?

I can't work out how I would count how many apples were sold in January, pears in Feb etc.

Comment: If you use `=text(a2, "dd-mmm-yyyy")` in a cell do you get a transformed date? Is there a text column header label in A1?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is necessarily a simpler formula, but maybe more scalable as you could add further conditions?

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A100,">="&DATE(2003,1,1),A1:A100,"<"&DATE(2003,2,1), B1:B100, "apples")
```

To get the number of apples in January.

Comment: That's super; it's worked perfectly, thanks very much!
I would also prefer to have a 'summary' front sheet and move that to another sheet of the workbook but it doesn't seem to be happy with that...any suggestions?

Comment: You'll want to 'lock' the references, to do click on the cell with the formula above and then click on each bit with a cell reference and hit the F4 function key on your keyboard once. The result will be something like `=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$100,">="&DATE(2003,1,1),$A$1:$A$100,"<"&DATE(2003,2,1), $B$1:$B$100, "apples")` You can then cut and paste the formula to another sheet. http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/lock-cells.html